# Select no mysql a partir de tal indice

Tags: mysql, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco e tem que retornar a tabela a partir de tal índice. por exemplo:

| ind | valor |
|001|  AAA |
|002|  BBB |
|003|  CCC |
|004|  DDD |
|005|  EEE |
|006|  FFF |
|007|  GGG |
|008|  HHH |

Eu teria que retornar os valores do ind de 5 pra baixo (6,7,8);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basta fazer o seguinte select

```
SELECT * FROM SUATABELA where ind >= '5'
```

caso não queira exibir o 5  fica assim

```
SELECT * FROM SUATABELA where ind > '5'
```

lembrando que o SUATABELA é o nome da sua tabela no db